# Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]");

Tags: java, regex

In this statement, taken from the Pagerank source code:

```
Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]");
```

What does the pattern mean? I have tried studying it, it says 2 slashes mean a single slash, but what are the `.+?`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This string literal:

```
"\\[.+?\\]"
```

means this string:

```
\[.+?\]
```

So this expression:

```
Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]");
```

means this regex:

```
\[.+?\]
```

which means "a literal `[`, followed by one or more characters — preferably as few as possible — followed by `]`". (`.` means "any character other than newline"; `+?` means "one or more of what I just said, and preferably as few as possible".) So overall, the regex matches `[____]`, where `____` can be anything that doesn't contain a newline, as long as it's at least one character long; and where `____` *won't* (normally) contain a `]` except possibly as the very first character.

For more information about `Pattern` and regexes in Java, see [the documentation for the `Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Very good explanation. Especially the corner case where the regex matches `[]...]` is important to mention.