# How do I escape this string in java. I'm using it as a regex for Pattern.compile

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting an invalid escape sequence error for this string. How can I escape it in my java code ?

```
 "^(?:(2\d\d\d)\s+)?(?:Comm\. Rep\.\s+)?(?:CONG\s+)?(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(?:No\.\s+)?(\S+)(?:\s+\(.*?\))?$"
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880070/pattern-compile

Comment: Doesn't anybody use the search function anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash (`\`) itself [must](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) be escaped:

```
"^(?:(2\\d\\d\\d)\\s+)?(?:Comm\\. Rep\\.\\s+)?(?:CONG\\s+)?(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(?:No\\.\\s+)?(\\S+)(?:\\s+\\(.*?\\))?$"
```